# Random groups of elements of a dictionary

Tags: python, random, dictionary

I've got a dictionary of 100 items and I've to create 10 groups of 10 elements of that dicionary. The elements of one group have to be selected in a random way from the elements of the dictionary. How can I do it?

Comment: Values or keys? Or both?

Comment: I'm sry I don't understand. You have a huge dict with 100 entries. You want to split that into 10 dicts, each containing 10 entries ?

Comment: Both. The structure of the dictionary is {id:(element1, element2, element3)}. id goes from 0 to 99. So in my group I've to choose a random number form 0 to 99 and get this element from the dictionary. This way, until get 10 groups of 10 elements.

Comment: And the elements can't be repeated in the groups. All elements of the dictionary have to be randomly distributed in the 10 groups. The groups set could be a list.

Comment: A list of what; values?

Comment: You're don't actually want to pick random elements here; you want all the elements, in random order. So move them from a dictionary into an ordered collection like a list, shuffle the list randomly, the reassemble dicts from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a generator to produce random values:

```
import random

def random_group(d, size=10):
    keys = list(d.keys())
    random.shuffle(keys)
    for i in range(0, len(keys), size):
         yield [(key, d[key]) for key in keys[i:i + size]]
```

This produces groups of 10 `(key, value)` pairs at a time:

```
for group in random_group(your_dictionary):
    print group
```

You can adjust the function to produce just keys, just values or dictionaries instead:

```
yield keys[i:i + size]                          # list of keys
yield [d[key] for key in keys[i:i + size]]      # list of values
yield {key: d[key] for key in keys[i:i + size]} # dictionary
```

Comment: Im trying it and i'm obtaining: TypeError: shuffle() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)... Anyway, using this method, there is the possibility of one element repeated in more than one grupo, isn't it?

Comment: The most important requirement is that one element of the dictionary can't be repeated in the groups

Comment: @user1068980: error fixed (forgot to actually specify what we are shuffling). No, there will *not* be any repeats.

Comment: @user1068980: The keys are always unique in a dictionary; I list the keys *once*, shuffle them, then pick 10 at a time until done.

Comment: @user1068980: Use the last option; replace the existing `yield` line with the line marked `# dictionary`.